# E/SQLiteDatabase( 8898): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0 SQLITE_OK): Could not open the database in read/write mode

Tags: android, database, flutter, sqlite

I'm having trouble opening an existing database. SQLite. I have prepared a database which contains 4 tables with data.

In my manifest i add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I upload my database in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.minwentaryzacja/files/database/InwentaryzacjaDane.db File exist 100%

In addition, I know that Android from version 11 upwards requires permission to read files from the external memory of the phone.

```
    onPressed: () async {
                    PermissionStatus _permisionStatus =
                        await Permission.storage.request();
                    if (_permisionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          const SnackBar(
                              content: Text("Permission storage")));
                    }

                    if (_permisionStatus == PermissionStatus.denied) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          const SnackBar(
                              content:
                                  Text("This permisison is recommended")));
                    }
                    if (_permisionStatus ==
                        PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
                      print("nie ma zgody");
                      await Permission.storage.request();
                      openAppSettings();
                    }
                  },
                )),
```

I have also added this permission and it works.

Using the Android 12.0 SDK 31 Emulator I am getting an error while reading the database.

```
E/SQLiteDatabase( 8898): Failed to open database '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.minwentaryzacja/files/database/InwentaryzacjaDane.db'.
E/SQLiteDatabase( 8898): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0 SQLITE_OK): Could not open the database in read/write mode.
E/SQLiteDatabase( 8898):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
E/SQLiteDatabase( 8898):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:224)
E/SQLiteDatabase( 8898):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:205)
E/SQLiteDatabase( 8898):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:505)
E/SQLiteDatabase( 8898):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
E/SQLiteDatabase( 8898):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:198)
```

The strange thing is that when I generate the APK version and install it on my physical device Realme Android 12.0 After joining to the database directory, everything displays me correctly and shows the data from the Table that the database contains.

The emulator shows an error android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0 SQLITE_OK): Could not open the database in read/write mode.

```
Future<Database?> get db async {
    if (_db != null) return _db;
    _db = await initDB();
    return _db;
  }



  initDB() async {
    
      try {
  if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
    final storageDir = await getExternalStorageDirectories();
    String path = join('${storageDir![0].path}/database', _databaseName);
    print(path);
    io.File file = io.File(path);
    var theDB = await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
    );
    print("Znaleziono bazę danych");
 
    return theDB;
  } else {
    throw Exception("Storage permission not granted");
  }
} catch (e) {
  print("Błąd inicjalizacji bazy danych: $e");
  rethrow;
}
```